# How to flat data by joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have three tables as follows:

```
T1:
+----+--------+--------+
| id | f1     | f2     |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | a      | c      |
| 2  | b      | d      |
+----+--------+--------+

T2:
+----+----+--------+--------+----+
| id | T1 | f1     | f2     | T3 |
+----+----+--------+--------+----+
| 1  | 1  | aa     | 100    | 1  |
| 2  | 1  | bb     | 200    | 1  |
| 3  | 2  | aa     | 56     | 2  |
| 4  | 2  | bb     | 550    | 2  |
| 5  | 2  | cc     | -120   | 3  |
+----+----+--------+--------+----+

T3:
+----+--------+--------+
| id | f4     | f5     |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | aaa    | x      |
| 2  | bbb    | y      |
| 3  | ccc    | z      |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I need to flat these tables based on T1 table. So I need a select query to generate this result from joining T1 with T2 and T3:

```
+-------+----+----+-----+-----+-------------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| T1_id | f1 | f2 | aa  | bb  | sum(aa, bb) | cc   | aaa | bbb | ccc |
+-------+----+----+-----+-----+-------------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 1     | a  | c  | 100 | 200 | 300         |      | x   |     |     |
| 2     | b  | d  | 56  | 550 | 610         | -120 |     | y   | z   |
+-------+----+----+-----+-----+-------------+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I guess it is a `row as column` problem that solved by `pivot` table but I don't know how to do it in `postgresql`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it always going to be just values `aa`, `bb`, `cc` in `T2` or is the number of `f1` values dynamic? Same question for `T3`. If the answer is "Dynamic" then I wouldn't do this in postgres. If it is always a static list of values in `f1` then just deal with each table individually to shape it the way you want using CASE expressions or pivot functionality and then join those result sets/subqueries.

Comment: @JNevill All fields are dynamic. Moreover I've simplified the problem to find the solution of the main problem and then tweak it for joining ~7 or more tables. What do you mean from "I wouldn't do this in postgres"? Do you mean it is impossible in postgres?